# Two Entity with Common identifier @id in HIbernate

Tags: hibernate, entity-relationship, hibernate-mapping, hibernate-annotations

I am Using Spring3+Hibernate 3.0. I Have two beans (@Entity) Projects And Participants. I want both beans(Projects and Participants) should have common @ID identifier it means projects and participants table will have common primary key. How Can I use @embededID or @Embedable to achieve that? Thanx in Advance.

Comment: Your question is not clear ... Are the 2 objects stored in the same table ?